# Which IP is used by Virtual Box for Internet Communication (if I'm running a VM)?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, internet-connection

short question:
Which IP is used by Virtual Box for Internet Communication if running a VM ?
Is it the IP - Address generated by the VM I use, or is the
query (communication task) done with the IP of the Computer that runs Virtual Box ?

regards
RNNUSr11

Comment: Please read [Chapter 6. Virtual Networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which IP is used by Virtual Box for Internet Communication (if I'm
> running a VM)?

It depends on whether the VM connection is NAT (Default) or Bridged (not Default).

Let us say your Host is 192.168.1.101 which is from the router.

Then if Bridged, the VM will be (say) 192.168.1.103 or like, which is also from the router.

If NAT (Default), the VM will be (say) 192.168.77.100 or like.

Notice the NAT Subnet is 77 and Bridged uses the Router Subnet which is 1 . Very different. NAT comes from the VBOX internal DHCP server.

I trust this helps.

Comment: Thx for the answer.                                                                                                                         I found a good Video on that topic on Youtube for anyone seeing this:    'Virtualisation: Bridged, NAT, host-only - Virtual Machine connection types. '     and thx again, hv a good day.

Comment: You should consider marking my answer as helpful or as answer.